# How to add a button to a layout in another .xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is the code I have in `mainActivity`. I want to add a button in the layout but in another activity. How can I do this?

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setText(name);
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btnTag.setId(tel);
layout.addView(btnTag);
```

Comment: What you're suggesting is possible, though difficult, and not efficient or practical. What is the end result you're trying to accomplish with this? I would guess that there is a better way than passing the entire view itself, such as just recreating the view in the new activity.

Comment: @WoogieNoogie I learned to do it as I wrote :( But it only works when we create a button in the same activity, and unfortunately i don't know how to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

As @WoogieNoogie said, certainly there is much better ways to do what you are looking for, but if it is a must then save add button to the layout and keep it invisible, then set a Boolean variable and save it into preferences, then on activity oncreate read preference Boolean state and set visibility as visible or gone.
I hope you know how to work with preferences.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GraphTemperature GT = new GraphTemperature(getApplicationContext());             
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.statsviewlayout);
    Button buyButton = new Button(this);
    buyButton.setText(R.string.button_back);
    buyButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(GT); // line 27
    layout.addView(buyButton);       
    setContentView(layout);           
}
```

Comment: One problem - I don't know how many buttons I need. I need to make buttons when I need them, because I don't know how many they will be.

Comment: Then just use the flag, then in activity "OnCreate" check the flag and create buttons and add to View. Do you know how to create new element and add to View?